# when I import a lib from cocoapods, xcode 7 can't find it

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I update xcode to 7, it seems there are some differences about "import", lots of errors tell me that I should use quote to import instead of "<>".

And in my project, I use cocoapods manage a lib "PLPlayerKit", xcode can't find it, wish to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `pod install` for the first time, Cocoapods will create a workspace for you. At this point, you must stop using `YourProject.xcodeproj` and must open `YourProject.xcworkspace`.

Then, you need to import your pods headers where you need them with `#import <MyPod.h>`

Comment: I used cocoapods for a long time in this project, it was ok with Xcode6, it get broken after update to Xcode7. I also managed other libs, just this PLPlayerKit can't be find, other libs are ok.

Comment: have tried update cocoapods, nothing happened, it seems to be some bugs of Xcode7

Comment: Try to remove PLPlayerKit from your Podfile, pod install and reinstall it ?